# Error TF80080 when connecting Microsoft Project to VSTS

Tags: team-foundation-server

I get error message below when I try to connect Microsoft Project 2016 to my Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS/VSO) project.

> TF80070: Team Foundation encountered an error while performing the operation...

Steps

- Create a new project file & save it
- Team > Choose Team Project
- Select my server
- Select my collection from the list
- Select my team project
- Click Connect

Please can you help me track the problem down?

Note: I am able to connect Excel to a VSTS query and retrieve results, so I believe this not to be a connectivity issue.

Comment: Same issue here, trying to follow the instructions here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the [Team Foundation Server Standalone Office Integration 2015 (free)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691127) solved this problem for me.